# Listview in android

Tags: android

I want to make a border in every row of Listview . How to do this?

Comment: Use a custom listview adapter. Inflate the xml and define a shape in drawable folder.Set the bacakground using the drawable shape.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a border around the whole item, the simplest way would be to define a [shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) in XML and set it as the background for the root of your row's layout. If you're doing anything fancy, though, you'll probably want to just make a stretchable [nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) for it. Also see ListView's `divider` and `dividerHeight` [properties](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android%3adivider) for the simple case where you just want to customize the line between list items.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer just include the following shape.xml as a background for listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
       <solid android:color="#003366"/>
       <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#33CCFF"/>

            <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp"
    android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />

</shape>
```